# How to solve ansi-term 01F40D character?

Tags: character-encoding

Tried this adding these lines to no avail to my init.el (excerpt):

```
  (prefer-coding-system       'utf-8)
  (set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
  (set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
  (set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)    
  (setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply don't have that character in your font, so Emacs renders a so-called ["tofu"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noto_fonts#Etymology) substitute showing which character codepoint it is.  If you choose a font which contains that character, it will be rendered normally.

Apparently that's a SNAKE character.  For me, it renders using Symbola:

```
            character:  (displayed as ) (codepoint 128013, #o372015, #x1f40d)
              charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
code point in charset: 0x1F40D
             to input: type "C-x 8 RET 1f40d" or "C-x 8 RET SNAKE"
          buffer code: #xF0 #x9F #x90 #x8D
            file code: #xF0 #x9F #x90 #x8D (encoded by coding system utf-8-unix)
              display: by this font (glyph code)
    xfthb:-Free-Symbola-normal-normal-semicondensed-*-17-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1 (#x2053)
```

If you have Symbola installed, you might try this:

```el
;; This magic means we fall back to Symbola for all missing unicode glyphs.
;; For Debian: apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" nil (font-spec :size 20 :name "Symbola:"))
```